# Quicksort - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

Learning to code, I will be attending a boot camp in early 2019 and looking to prepare for it. I have a Java book with the following code for an example of the quicksort algorithm, I have copied it directly from the book and it provides me the IndexOutOfBounds error. I understand it has to do with an Index's location that is being checked but may not exist, however, I can't tell what is wrong specifically. Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
// Try This 6-3: A simple version of the Quicksort. 

class Quicksort {

    // Set up a call to the actual Quicksort method.
    static void qsort(char items[]) {
        qs(items, 0, items.length-1);
    }

    // A recursive version of Quicksort for characters. 
    private static void qs(char items[], int left, int right)
    {
        int i, j;
        char x, y;

        i = left; j = right;
        x = items[(left+right)/2];

        do {
            while((items[i] < x) && (i < right))
                i++;

            while((x < items[j]) && (j > left))
                j--;

            if(i <= j) {
                y = items[i];
                items[i] = items[j];
                items[j] = y;

                i++; 
                j--;
            }
        } while(i <= j);

        if(left < j);
            qs(items, left, j);

        if(i < right)
            qs(items, i, right);
    }
}

class QSDemo { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char a[] = {'d', 'x', 'a', 'r', 'p', 'j', 'i'};
        int i; 

        System.out.println("Original array: ");

        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i]);

        System.out.println();

        // now, sort the array
        Quicksort.qsort(a);

        System.out.print("Sorted array: ");

        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
}*emphasized text*
```

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: `Java` !== `JavaScript`

Comment: @ThomasCatinella another user had already corrected the tags, you have just made them incorrect again. The language your code is written in is `java` not `javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have put an `;` after the `if` statement and that's the reason you're getting the error. Because of `;` , `qs()` will be called regardless of the `if` condition.

```
    if(left < j); qs(items, left, j); //<------problem
    ____________^
```

`if(left < j); qs(items, left, j);` should be  `if(left < j) qs(items, left, j);`

Comment: Well I feel stupid and blind! I was looking everywhere.  Thanks for the eyes!

Comment: @ThomasCatinella No problem! please close the question if you don't have any more issue.

Comment: New to Stack. I don't see where/how to close the question tbh. I can't delete it either.

Comment: @ThomasCatinella close means just click the right button if my answer helped you fix your issue. You don't need to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your second `if` loop in the `qs()` function, where it checks if `left` is less than `j`. You have added a semi-colon (may be accidentally) after the `if` statement. This causes the statement meant to be inside the `if` loop to be executed regardless of whether the `if` condition passes or not.

Here is what it should be:

```
if(left < j)             //remove semi-colon which was here
    qs(items, left, j);
```

Comment: Well I feel stupid and blind! I was looking everywhere.  Thanks for the eyes!

Comment: It happens at times with all @ThomasCatinella. No sweat.